# Parallel calculation of the sum of an array with OpenMPI & Debugging tips

Tags: c, debugging, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to convert a serial programma to parallel one using OpenMPI as practice. I used the following simple code to calculate the sum of an array, and tried to convert it to run on multiple nodes, but im getting an MPI_ERROR during runtime that I dont know how to debugg.

This is the simple code i wrote to do the calculations in serial.

```
//array serial

#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 50000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, sum, Tsum, data[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = i + 1;
    }

    Tsum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        Tsum = Tsum + data[i];
    }

    printf("Total Sum: %d \n", Tsum);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is how i converted to parallel with OpenMPI

```
//array parallel

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define SIZE 50000
MPI_Status status;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size, proc, rank, dest, index, i, source, chunksize, sum, Tsum;
    int data1[SIZE], data2[SIZE];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    proc = size;
    chunksize = SIZE / proc;

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        {
            data1[i] = i+1;
        }

        index = 0;

        for (dest = 1; dest <= proc; ++dest)
        {
            MPI_Send(&index, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&data1[index], chunksize, MPI_INT, dest, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            index = index + chunksize;
        }

        Tsum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < proc; ++i)
        {
            source = 1;
            MPI_Recv(&sum, 1, MPI_INT, source, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            Tsum = Tsum + sum;
            printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
            printf("Received from process %d, Sum: %d \n", source, sum);
        }

        printf("Total Sum received: %d \n All done \n", Tsum);
    }
    else if (rank > 0)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&index, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&data2[index], chunksize, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        sum = 0;

        for (int i = index; i < index + chunksize; ++i)
        {
            sum = sum + data2[i];
        }

        MPI_Send(&sum, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error im getting when im trying to run it

```
$mpirun -np 2 /lab/ap709 
$[andrew709:4092] *** An error occurred in MPI_Send
$[andrew709:4092] *** reported by process [512884737,0]
$[andrew709:4092] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
$[andrew709:4092] *** MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank
$[andrew709:4092] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
$[andrew709:4092] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Also, i wanted to ask, it there is any way to debugg parallel applications. In school even though we did C, C++ and Java as full semester classes, we never learned how to debugg. When an error occured, we searched the source code trying to see what went wrong. In my free time, i have very limited experience in GDB (a few hours max...) but i dont know how it can be useful in parallel applications.

Comment: OpenMPI has a whole [FAQ about debugging](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging). The most convenient way is using a graphical parallel debugger such as DDT. Those are commercial programs.

Comment: Just for your information, look at the MPI collective operations, s.t. MPI_Bcast, MPI_Scatter(v), and MPI_Reduce. First, that would enable you to shorten the code by removing most of the conditions and `for` loops. Second, these collective communication operations may offer you more efficient implementation than only a loop of send/recv on p processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had several bugs.

The first root loop was wrong, so with `-np 2` you would send to rank 2.

The second root loop was wrong -- it should match the corrected first loop.

A third bug, that only shows up with `-np` greater than 2 is that the root `MPI_Recv` is wrong. The program will hang.

I've corrected the program and annotated the source. I moved the essential code to a function. Each time I made a fix I added a new function with the fix so you can see the history of the debug process.

Since you also wanted help with debugging, I've added debugging code that I used to find the problems. I've used this sort of code many times before.

I've also added the output trace files at the bottom.

**Update:** There is a fourth bug. If the `-np` value minus 1 does *not* divide `SIZE` evenly, some of the last elements will not be summed (e.g. `-np 7`). I've added more annotation and added an additional function that fixes this.

Anyway, here's the code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
//array parallel

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef long long s64;

double tvzero;                          // initial start time

int opt_debug;                          // 1=trace
int opt_run;                            // version to run

int size;                               // MPI size
int rank;                               // MPI rank of current process
int proc;                               // number of child processes
int chunksize;                          // size of chunk
MPI_Status status;

#define TVSEC       1000000000

// tvget -- get time in nanoseconds
s64
tvget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    s64 nsec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);
    nsec = ts.tv_sec;
    nsec *= TVSEC;
    nsec += ts.tv_nsec;

    return nsec;
}

// tvgetf -- get time in fractional seconds
double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= TVSEC;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

void
_dbgprt(int lno,const char *fmt,...)
__attribute__((__format__(__printf__,2,3)));

#define dbgprt(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_debug >= _lvl) \
            _dbgprt(__LINE__,_fmt); \
    } while (0)

void
_dbgprt(int lno,const char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    double tvnow;
    char *bp;
    char bf[1000];

    bp = bf;

    tvnow = tvgetf();
    tvnow -= tvzero;

    bp += sprintf(bp,"[%.9f/R:%d/L:%d] ",tvnow,rank,lno);

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    bp += vsprintf(bp,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    fputs(bf,stdout);
}

// _dbgptr -- interpret pointer
char *
_dbgptr(const void *ptr,const char *sym,MPI_Datatype typ)
{
    char *bp;
    static char bf[100];

    bp = bf;
    *bp = 0;

    do {
        bp += sprintf(bp,"%s=",sym);

        if (typ == MPI_INT) {
            bp += sprintf(bp,"%d",*(int *) ptr);
            break;
        }

        bp += sprintf(bp,"%p",ptr);
    } while (0);

    return bf;
}

#define xMPI_Send(_ptr,_cnt,_typ,_torank,_tag,_comm) \
    do { \
        dbgprt(2,"MPI_Send ptr=[%s] cnt=%d typ=%s torank=%d tag=%d comm=%s\n", \
            _dbgptr(_ptr,#_ptr,_typ),_cnt,#_typ,_torank,_tag,#_comm); \
        MPI_Send(_ptr,_cnt,_typ,_torank,_tag,_comm); \
    } while (0)

#define xMPI_Recv(_ptr,_cnt,_typ,_fmrank,_tag,_comm,_status) \
    do { \
        dbgprt(2,"MPI_Recv ptr=%p cnt=%d typ=%s fmrank=%d tag=%d comm=%s\n", \
            _ptr,_cnt,#_typ,_fmrank,_tag,#_comm); \
        MPI_Recv(_ptr,_cnt,_typ,_fmrank,_tag,_comm,_status); \
    } while (0)

#define xMPI_Finalize() \
    do { \
        dbgprt(1,"MPI_Finalize\n"); \
        MPI_Finalize(); \
    } while (0)

#define SIZE 50000
int data1[SIZE];
int data2[SIZE];

// init -- initialize array and return sum
int
init(void)
{
    int i;
    int Tsum;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        data1[i] = i + 1;

    Tsum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        Tsum += data1[i];

    printf("Total Sum: %d \n",Tsum);

    return Tsum;
}

// run_orig -- original code with all bugs noted
void
run_orig(void)
{
    int i;
    int dest;
    int source;
    int Tsum;
    int Rsum;
    int sum;
    int index;

    // BUG(1a): this should be one less (e.g. for -np 2, root=0, child=1)
    proc = size;

    // BUG(4): if SIZE is not a multiple of proc, the last few elements will
    // _not_ be processed -- the last child must get a larger chunk size, so in
    // addition to sending the index to each child, we must send it a custom
    // chunk size
    chunksize = SIZE / proc;

    if (rank == 0) {
        Tsum = init();

        // send split of array to children
        // BUG(1b): this loop goes one beyond the last child and caused the send
        // to blow up
        index = 0;
        for (dest = 1; dest <= proc; ++dest) {
            xMPI_Send(&index,1,MPI_INT,dest,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            xMPI_Send(&data1[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,dest,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            index = index + chunksize;
        }

        // collect sum of children
        // BUG(2): this for loop is wrong -- it should match the one above
        Rsum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < proc; ++i) {
            // BUG(3): source should be "i"
            source = 1;
            xMPI_Recv(&sum,1,MPI_INT,source,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            Rsum = Rsum + sum;
            printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
            printf("Received from process %d, Sum: %d \n",source,sum);
        }

        printf("Total Sum received: %d -- %s\n",
            Rsum,(Rsum == Tsum) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }

    else {
        xMPI_Recv(&index,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        xMPI_Recv(&data2[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

        sum = 0;
        for (i = index; i < index + chunksize; ++i)
            sum += data2[i];

        xMPI_Send(&sum,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

// run_edit1 -- no changes to original
void
run_edit1(void)
{
    int i;
    int cldno;
    int Tsum;
    int Rsum;
    int sum;
    int index;
    int source;

    proc = size;

    chunksize = SIZE / proc;

    if (rank == 0) {
        Tsum = init();

        // send split of array to children
        index = 0;
        for (cldno = 1; cldno <= proc; ++cldno) {
            xMPI_Send(&index,1,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            xMPI_Send(&data1[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            index = index + chunksize;
        }

        // collect sum of children
        Rsum = 0;
        for (cldno = 0;  cldno < proc;  ++cldno) {
            source = 1;
            xMPI_Recv(&sum,1,MPI_INT,source,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            Rsum += sum;
            printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
            printf("Received from process %d, Sum: %d \n",cldno,sum);
        }

        printf("Total Sum received: %d -- %s\n",
            Rsum,(Rsum == Tsum) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }

    else {
        xMPI_Recv(&index,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        xMPI_Recv(&data2[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

        sum = 0;
        for (i = index; i < index + chunksize; ++i)
            sum += data2[i];

        xMPI_Send(&sum,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

// run_edit2 -- fixed child count
void
run_edit2(void)
{
    int i;
    int cldno;
    int Tsum;
    int Rsum;
    int sum;
    int index;
    int source;

    // BUGFIX #1 -- child count must be one less than size
    proc = size - 1;

    chunksize = SIZE / proc;

    if (rank == 0) {
        Tsum = init();

        // send split of array to children
        index = 0;
        for (cldno = 1; cldno <= proc; ++cldno) {
            xMPI_Send(&index,1,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            xMPI_Send(&data1[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            index = index + chunksize;
        }

        // collect sum of children
        Rsum = 0;
        for (cldno = 0;  cldno < proc;  ++cldno) {
            source = 1;
            xMPI_Recv(&sum,1,MPI_INT,source,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            Rsum += sum;
            printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
            printf("Received from process %d, Sum: %d \n",cldno,sum);
        }

        printf("Total Sum received: %d -- %s\n",
            Rsum,(Rsum == Tsum) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }

    else {
        xMPI_Recv(&index,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        xMPI_Recv(&data2[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

        sum = 0;
        for (i = index; i < index + chunksize; ++i)
            sum += data2[i];

        xMPI_Send(&sum,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

// run_edit3 -- fixed second root loop and MPI_Recv
void
run_edit3(void)
{
    int i;
    int cldno;
    int Tsum;
    int Rsum;
    int sum;
    int index;

    // BUGFIX #1 -- child count must be one less than size
    proc = size - 1;

    chunksize = SIZE / proc;

    if (rank == 0) {
        Tsum = init();

        // send split of array to children
        index = 0;
        for (cldno = 1; cldno <= proc; ++cldno) {
            xMPI_Send(&index,1,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            xMPI_Send(&data1[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            index = index + chunksize;
        }

        // collect sum of children
        // BUGFIX #2 -- loop was wrong and the source arg must be the child rank
        Rsum = 0;
        for (cldno = 1;  cldno <= proc;  ++cldno) {
            xMPI_Recv(&sum,1,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            Rsum += sum;
            printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
            printf("Received from process %d, Sum: %d \n",cldno,sum);
        }

        printf("Total Sum received: %d -- %s\n",
            Rsum,(Rsum == Tsum) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }

    else {
        xMPI_Recv(&index,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        xMPI_Recv(&data2[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

        sum = 0;
        for (i = index; i < index + chunksize; ++i)
            sum += data2[i];

        xMPI_Send(&sum,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

// run_edit4 -- fixed chunk size allocation
void
run_edit4(void)
{
    int i;
    int cldno;
    int Tsum;
    int Rsum;
    int sum;
    int sendsize;
    int totsize;
    int index;

    // BUGFIX #1 -- child count must be one less than size
    proc = size - 1;

    totsize = SIZE;
    chunksize = totsize / proc;

    if (rank == 0) {
        Tsum = init();

        // send split of array to children
        index = 0;
        for (cldno = 1; cldno <= proc; ++cldno, totsize -= sendsize) {
            // BUGFIX #3a -- not every child node gets the same amount
            if (cldno < proc)
                sendsize = chunksize;
            else
                sendsize = totsize;
            xMPI_Send(&index,1,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            xMPI_Send(&sendsize,1,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            xMPI_Send(&data1[index],sendsize,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            index = index + sendsize;
        }

        // collect sum of children
        // BUGFIX #2 -- loop was wrong and the source arg must be the child rank
        Rsum = 0;
        for (cldno = 1;  cldno <= proc;  ++cldno) {
            xMPI_Recv(&sum,1,MPI_INT,cldno,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            Rsum += sum;
            printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
            printf("Received from process %d, Sum: %d \n",cldno,sum);
        }

        printf("Total Sum received: %d -- %s\n",
            Rsum,(Rsum == Tsum) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }

    else {
        // BUGFIX #3b -- not every child node gets the same amount
        xMPI_Recv(&index,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        xMPI_Recv(&chunksize,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        xMPI_Recv(&data2[index],chunksize,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

        sum = 0;
        for (i = index; i < index + chunksize; ++i)
            sum += data2[i];

        xMPI_Send(&sum,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    // NOTE: this will vary a bit with rank
    // to do the job properly we'd need the root to bcast this -- see below
    tvzero = tvgetf();

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'R':
            cp += 2;
            opt_run = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'T':
            cp += 2;
            opt_debug = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // root send to all children
    if (opt_debug)
        MPI_Bcast(&tvzero,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // show our pid so we can map it to rank [which is more meaningful]
    dbgprt(1,"PID pid=%d\n",getpid());

    switch (opt_run) {
    case 1:
        run_edit1();
        break;
    case 2:
        run_edit2();
        break;
    case 3:
        run_edit3();
        break;
    case 4:
        run_edit4();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    xMPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here are the logs [combined into one to save space]:

```
# test #1 edit #1 with -np=2 -T9
[manderly:6620] *** An error occurred in MPI_Send
[manderly:6620] *** reported by process [3255828481,0]
[manderly:6620] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[manderly:6620] *** MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank
[manderly:6620] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[manderly:6620] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[0.014549255/R:0/L:480] PID pid=6620
[0.014554262/R:1/L:480] PID pid=6621
[0.014572620/R:1/L:259] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffc98d18a6c cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
Total Sum: 1250025000
[0.014715672/R:0/L:239] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=0] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.014730692/R:0/L:240] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=1] cnt=25000 typ=MPI_INT torank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.014730930/R:1/L:260] MPI_Recv ptr=0x603960 cnt=25000 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.014817476/R:0/L:239] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=25000] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=2 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.014842749/R:1/L:266] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=312512500] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.014861822/R:1/L:499] MPI_Finalize

# test #2 edit #2 with -np=2 -T0
Total Sum: 1250025000
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 0, Sum: 1250025000
Total Sum received: 1250025000 -- PASS

# test #3 edit #2 with -np=5 -T9
[0.028285980/R:0/L:480] PID pid=6632
[0.028294086/R:1/L:480] PID pid=6633
[0.028315544/R:1/L:313] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffe22a554ec cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028294325/R:4/L:480] PID pid=6637
[0.028332472/R:4/L:313] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffd5ed6a77c cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028387308/R:2/L:480] PID pid=6634
[0.028410435/R:2/L:313] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7fff6f23896c cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028449297/R:3/L:480] PID pid=6635
[0.028471947/R:3/L:313] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffd23af2ecc cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
Total Sum: 1250025000
[0.028527975/R:0/L:293] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=0] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028543711/R:0/L:294] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=1] cnt=12500 typ=MPI_INT torank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028544903/R:1/L:314] MPI_Recv ptr=0x603960 cnt=12500 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028627157/R:0/L:293] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=12500] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=2 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028636694/R:0/L:294] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=12501] cnt=12500 typ=MPI_INT torank=2 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028637648/R:2/L:314] MPI_Recv ptr=0x60fcb0 cnt=12500 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028641224/R:1/L:320] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=78131250] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028657198/R:1/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.028701305/R:0/L:293] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=25000] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=3 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028716326/R:0/L:294] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=25001] cnt=12500 typ=MPI_INT torank=3 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028719425/R:2/L:320] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=234381250] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028721094/R:3/L:314] MPI_Recv ptr=0x61c000 cnt=12500 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028738737/R:2/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.028776169/R:0/L:293] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=37500] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=4 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028784752/R:0/L:294] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=37501] cnt=12500 typ=MPI_INT torank=4 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028797865/R:3/L:320] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=390631250] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028819084/R:3/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.028877974/R:4/L:314] MPI_Recv ptr=0x628350 cnt=12500 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028944492/R:0/L:302] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffe7db6e4b8 cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 0, Sum: 78131250
[0.028969765/R:0/L:302] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffe7db6e4b8 cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028957367/R:4/L:320] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=546881250] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.028982162/R:4/L:499] MPI_Finalize
TIMEOUT!!!

# test #4 edit #3 with -np=5 -T0
Total Sum: 1250025000
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 1, Sum: 78131250
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 2, Sum: 234381250
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 3, Sum: 390631250
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 4, Sum: 546881250
Total Sum received: 1250025000 -- PASS

# test #5 edit #3 with -np=7 -T9
[0.043676138/R:0/L:480] PID pid=6662
[0.043689251/R:1/L:480] PID pid=6663
[0.043709040/R:1/L:366] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffc571a085c cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.043683767/R:4/L:480] PID pid=6666
[0.043709040/R:4/L:366] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffd9e8ea57c cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.043860435/R:3/L:480] PID pid=6665
[0.043884993/R:3/L:366] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffd1f26c0fc cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.043950558/R:5/L:480] PID pid=6669
[0.043974400/R:5/L:366] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffc171ddf2c cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.043961048/R:2/L:480] PID pid=6664
[0.043980122/R:2/L:366] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffde0a06dec cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.043968439/R:6/L:480] PID pid=6670
[0.043987513/R:6/L:366] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7ffe4afba88c cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
Total Sum: 1250025000
[0.044004679/R:0/L:346] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=0] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044021130/R:0/L:347] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=1] cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT torank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044066429/R:1/L:367] MPI_Recv ptr=0x603960 cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044160843/R:0/L:346] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=8333] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=2 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044172764/R:0/L:347] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=8334] cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT torank=2 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044173002/R:2/L:367] MPI_Recv ptr=0x60bb94 cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044213533/R:1/L:373] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=34723611] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044217110/R:0/L:346] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=16666] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=3 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044228792/R:0/L:347] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=16667] cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT torank=3 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044233561/R:2/L:373] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=104162500] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044246435/R:2/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.044233799/R:3/L:367] MPI_Recv ptr=0x613dc8 cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044275522/R:0/L:346] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=24999] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=4 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044286489/R:4/L:367] MPI_Recv ptr=0x61bffc cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044291496/R:3/L:373] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=173601389] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044314146/R:3/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.044286251/R:0/L:347] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=25000] cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT torank=4 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044338703/R:0/L:346] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=33332] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=5 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044353485/R:0/L:347] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=33333] cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT torank=5 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044402599/R:0/L:346] MPI_Send ptr=[&index=41665] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=6 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044354916/R:4/L:373] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=243040278] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044372797/R:4/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.044359684/R:5/L:367] MPI_Recv ptr=0x624230 cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044411659/R:5/L:373] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=312479167] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044427156/R:5/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.044423819/R:6/L:367] MPI_Recv ptr=0x62c464 cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044469357/R:6/L:373] MPI_Send ptr=[&sum=381918056] cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT torank=0 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044484377/R:6/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.044419050/R:0/L:347] MPI_Send ptr=[&data1[index]=41666] cnt=8333 typ=MPI_INT torank=6 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
[0.044459820/R:0/L:355] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7fffd9e14708 cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=1 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 1, Sum: 34723611
[0.044672012/R:0/L:355] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7fffd9e14708 cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=2 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 2, Sum: 104162500
[0.044713497/R:0/L:355] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7fffd9e14708 cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=3 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 3, Sum: 173601389
[0.044723034/R:0/L:355] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7fffd9e14708 cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=4 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 4, Sum: 243040278
[0.044659376/R:1/L:499] MPI_Finalize
[0.044735193/R:0/L:355] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7fffd9e14708 cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=5 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 5, Sum: 312479167
[0.044743538/R:0/L:355] MPI_Recv ptr=0x7fffd9e14708 cnt=1 typ=MPI_INT fmrank=6 tag=0 comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 6, Sum: 381918056
Total Sum received: 1249925001 -- FAIL
[0.044760466/R:0/L:499] MPI_Finalize

# test #6 edit #4 with -np=7 -T0
Total Sum: 1250025000
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 1, Sum: 34723611
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 2, Sum: 104162500
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 3, Sum: 173601389
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 4, Sum: 243040278
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 5, Sum: 312479167
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Received from process 6, Sum: 382018055
Total Sum received: 1250025000 -- PASS
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
for (dest = 1; dest <= proc; ++dest)
```

should be

```
for (dest = 1; dest < proc; ++dest)
```

You are trying to send to a rank with a label of 2, but with only 2 ranks, you only have ranks 0 and 1

Also, when you are receiving on rank 0, you have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < proc; ++i)
```

Which implies you plan to receive from yourself, but you do not have a corresponding send.